# Cron does not run from /root

Tags: linux, cron

If I run a script from `/home/<user>/<dir>/script.sh`, as root, the cron works pretty well. But If I run the script from `/root/<dir>/script.sh` (as root, again), the cron does not seem to work.

Comment: without the code it will get difficult ;-)

Comment: yeah, we need the code and we need to know exactly how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Having run afoul of various default $PATHs in the past when using 'cron', I always spell in full the absolute $PATH for each executable file and each target file.  I always assume that  'cron' has NO $PATH set and has NO current-working-directory.

In other words don't use a command like

```
       "myprocess  abc*.txt"
```

but do it in full like

```
        "/usr/localbin/myprocess    /home/jvs/abc*.txt".
```

Alternatively, create a bash script which does the job, and call that bash script with a full absolute path, such as

```
       "/usr/local/bin/myprocess_abc_txts".
```

If you need to have some flexibility in the script, use environment variables which are set specifically within the bash script you call with 'cron'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add a little more information.  I'd guess it is a permissions thing though.  Add the permissions of the file, the directories, and the line in your crontab so we can help.  Also, if you are putting this in /root, are you running this in root's crontab?

Answer (score 2):

Remember the environment - especially when run by `cron` rather than by root.  When cron runs something, you probably don't have anything much set of your environment, unlike when you run a command via `at`.  It is also not clear what your current directory will be.  So, for commands that will be run by `cron`, use a script (as you're already doing) and make sure it sets enough of the environment for it to run.  And make sure your environment setting code is not interactive!

On my machines, I have a mechanism such that the cron entry reads (for example):

```
23 1 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/ksh /work1/jleffler/bin/Cron/weekday
```

The `weekday` script in the `Cron` directory is a link to a standard script that first sets the environment and then runs the command `/work1/jleffler/bin/weekday` (in this case - it uses the name of the command to determine what to run).

The actual script in the `Cron` directory is:

```
:       "$Id: runcron.sh,v 2.1 2001/02/27 00:53:22 jleffler Exp $"
#
#       Commands to be performed by Cron (no debugging options)

#       Set environment -- not done by cron (usually switches HOME)
. $HOME/.cronfile

base=`basename $0`
cmd=${REAL_HOME:-/real/home}/bin/$base

if [ ! -x $cmd ]
then cmd=${HOME}/bin/$base
fi

exec $cmd ${@:+"$@"}
```

I've been using it a while now - this version since 2001 - and it works a treat for me.  I'm using a basic (Sun Solaris 10) implementation of `cron`; there may be new features in new versions of `cron` on other platforms to make some of this unnecessary.  (The `$REAL_HOME` stuff is a weirdness of mine; pretend it says `$HOME` - though that makes some of the script unnecessary for you.)  The `.cronfile` is responsible for the environment setting - it does quite a lot, but that's my problem, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're looking for relative directories/files in the script which are located when running it from /home/ but not from /root, because /root is not in /home/root nor would it look like a users homefolder in /home/

Can you check and see if it is looking for relative files, or post the script?

On another note, why don't you just set it to run from a user's homefolder then?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run sh script is place your bash script in `/usr/bin` directory and simply run command `bash yourscript.sh` without adding `/usr/bin/` directory